# How to display a continious stream of decoded byte strings in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to display the serial output from my device to Tkinter's `Text Widget`, but i am getting this error `<function win_read at 0x0318F930>`. If i type a multiline string it will display it normally.
The serial output is a decoded byte string, with more than 1000 lines of string characters.

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('COM3', timeout=1)
ser.baudrate = 115200

def win_read():
    while True:
        output = ser.read(10000).decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        print(output)
        return

root = tk.Tk()
S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
T = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
quote = win_read
T.insert(tk.END, win_read)
tk.mainloop()
```

Am i using the right widget? I tried printing the whole output at a label too, but it didn't work.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is unclear if it is about displaying a stream in a tkinter widget, decoding a stream from some unknown source (not provided), or merely obtaining the stream output to do whatever needs to be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis to call your function, here: `quote = stream_read()`. This is where the `<function win_read at 0x0318F930>` displayed in your widget comes from.
You are also sending the stream obtained to `stdout` (via `print`) instead of making it available to your GUI.

Here is an example with a simulated stream:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def stream():
    while True:
        s = []
        for _ in range(random.randrange(4)):
            s.append(str(random.randrange(10)))
        yield ''.join(s)


def stream_read():    # <- maybe have a buffer mechanism here? Impossible to say more without access to the stream.  
    st = stream()
    return next(st)


def update_stream():
    print('.')
    T.insert(tk.END, stream_read())
    root.after(100, update_stream)


root = tk.Tk()

S = tk.Scrollbar(root)
T = tk.Text(root, height=4, width=50)
S.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
T.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
S.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
quote = stream_read()
T.insert(tk.END, quote)

update_stream()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the question, i didn't want to display some random numbers, i wanted to display DECODED byte strings from my serial communication with the device. I wasn't missing any parenthesis, if i had the parenthesis in my function i would get this error : `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!text insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"`.

Comment: You are welcome! You asked "how to display a continuous stream of strings", because your code was displaying `<function win_read at 0x0318F930>` instead! You also asked if you were using the correct widget, and mentioned that you had tried a `label` but were unable to make it work! You did not provide access to a stream, nor did you mention anything about decoding a stream, which is why I provided a substitute for a stream! I answered your question as you asked it.